# How to create file in a project folder in Java?

Tags: java

in JsonOperation class:

```
public void writeJson(String path, JSONObject passedJsonObj){
    File file = new File(path);
    try{
        if (!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        writer.write(passedJsonObj.toJSONString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

in my main calling class:

```
    LocalDate todayDate = LocalDate.now();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String dateString = todayDate.format(formatter).toString();

    JsonOperation jsonOp = new JsonOperation();
    jsonOp.writeJson("srcsample/SaveData.json", jsonOp.toJsonObj("dateToday", dateString) );
```

While running this, I got these errors:

```
java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
    at sample.JsonOperation.writeJson(JsonOperation.java:50)
    at sample.Main.saveData(Main.java:58)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:29)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$52/384953125.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/113087735.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$50/949297714.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/59984698.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/665838427.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I change

```
jsonOp.writeJson("\\src\\sample\\SaveData.json", jsonOp.toJsonObj("dateToday", dateString) );
```

into

```
jsonOp.writeJson("SaveData.json", jsonOp.toJsonObj("dateToday", dateString) );
```

it doesn't give me any error but it creates the file outside the **src** folder.  What should I do to create the file inside sample folder?

My project heirarchy: `WordToday>src>sample`

Comment: I just realized **sample** is actually a java package. But it is shown as a folder in my file explorer.

Comment: Packages *are* in folders in a Java project. That's how Java works. But I would recommend (strongly) against writing into your project-that will make it dependent on having the source tree available. Use a configurable, external location.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my project i created a "logs" folder outside the src folder with the file definition:

```
File file = new File("logs/file.txt");
```

So I expect you can create a file there with File("/file.txt")

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will go with this.

Comment: yup it does. But I don't understand why I can't create file inside src folder.

Comment: Then do File(/src/file.txt) and your in src

Answer (score 7):

Try using the asbolute path. When you use the relative path, the file is not being created inside the folder you think it is.

You can try the following to check where your relative path is:

```
Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
System.out.println("Current relative path is: " + s);
```

Try it and let me know.

EDIT:
See this for more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html

Comment: Same error. I can only create file outside the src folder

Answer (score 4):

1. For creating in any folder

   `File file = new File("C:\\Users\\YourUserName\\Directory\\fileName.txt");`
2. For in Project directory

   `File = new File("directory/fileName.txt");`
3. Check if file exists, if not create new

   `if (!file.exists()) {
   file.createNewFile();
   }`

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you are doing an application to production level, locally those things will basically work, but otherwise you will be stuck for a long time, first try to understand your servers folder usage by typing the following:

```
Path currentPathPosition = Paths.get("");
ResponseEntity.ok(currentPathPoosition.getAbsolutePath());
```